# Tools in Data Science

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining

I am a new one in Data Science and Machine Learning. I have some experience in Java, Python, SQL, Jupyter and most polular libraries like scikit-learn, numpy, pandas, tensorflow, keras. What tools would you recommend else? And what OS is more suitable for DS (I've heard that Debian)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few essential packages come to mind that every Python statisticians must know:

[SciPy](https://scipy.org/scipylib/), which is based on NumPy, extends NumPy capabilities. You can do linear algebra, probability theory, integral calculus and many more tasks with SciPy.

[StatsModels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) - estimating of statistical models, conducting statistical tests, and statistical data exploration.

[Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/index.html) - 2-dimensional static plotting, from histograms and scatterplots to non-Cartesian coordinates graphs

[Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) - high-level API based on matplotlib. It has better default settings for statistical charts, along with a rich collection of visualizations including some complex types like time series, jointplots, and violin diagrams.